# How to find mac address in active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, mac-address

Can you get mac addresses from Active Directory using Powershell?  I am looking for a way to search for mac addresses in specific OUs if this is possible.  Overall, I would like a dynamic way to find mac addresses for computers connected to the domain even if they are turned off and I thought AD might be a good way to go if possible.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think that the [computer object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680987(v=vs.85).aspx) contains the MAC address, which is where the computer information is stored in active directory.

Comment: Although AD [does contain an attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676850(v=vs.85).aspx) for MAC address, it doesn't seem to be populated in my current domain.

Comment: I believe SCCM client has that option, however it doesn't seem to be in scope. Here is some "pseudo algorithm" which can help you script it. 

1. List all computers objects you want tested
2. Run query against all of them in Powershell (by fetching ipconfig.exe or Win32_NetworkAdapter)
3. Update OU objects accordingly with findings. 

This is just a "stub" of the script, I suggest you try to write it and get back here if you have issues :-)

Comment: The long-winded way: 1) get computer names from AD, 2) nslookup or `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry` their IPs and store in a var or hashtable 3) compare output of previous step with output of `arp -a`

Comment: @Raf arp -a will work only on LAN? ARP packets are not broadcasted further past the router, or at least I have not heard about such solution? I cannot lookup any MAC addresses that are outside my local network with this method, even though I am RDPed into couple of servers at the moment.

Comment: @Koliat - `arp -a` will work over LAN and properly configured IPSEC or PPTP tunnels, so on a standard AD setup tis should be OK. `arp -a` would then be best run on a DC as individual client computers need to contact it at some point.

Comment: @Raf will it work on multiple domain controllers site ? in my environment different clients contact different DCs depending on their location and im not sure if arpcache gets replicated... Im quite surprised to hear its going to work thus I ask :-)

Comment: @Koliat - my approach has limited functionality and you just pointed out one of them...

Comment: You might have better luck getting a list of computer names in the OU from AD, then taking that back to your DHCP server to get the MAC address off the lease information.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have said, that information is not held in Active Directory.

Consider using a computer start-up script to populate a field in AD with the mac address.

Also consider that many devices can have multiple mac addresses, some laptops may have 3 even.

This is an example based on a script I use (its in VBScript):

```
Option Explicit

Dim objRootDSE, objNetwork, objWMIService, objComputer
Dim strComputer, strMacAddresses
Dim colNetworkAdapterConfiguration, objNetworkAdapterConfiguration
Dim adoConnection, adoRecordset

strComputer = "."
strMacAddresses = ""

Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colNetworkAdapterConfiguration = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterType = 'Ethernet 802.3' OR AdapterType = 'Wireless'")

strMacAddresses = ""

If Not colNetworkAdapterConfiguration Is Nothing Then
    For Each objNetworkAdapterConfiguration in colNetworkAdapterConfiguration
        If strMacAddresses <> "" Then
            strMacAddresses = strMacAddresses & " "
        End If
        strMacAddresses = strMacAddresses & Trim(objNetworkAdapterConfiguration.MACAddress)
    Next
End If

Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set adoRecordset = adoConnection.Execute("<LDAP://" & objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">;(&(objectCategory=Computer)(name=" & objNetwork.Computername & "));adspath;subtree")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
End If

If Not adoRecordset.EOF Then
    Set objComputer = GetObject(adoRecordset.Fields(0).Value)
    objComputer.Put "extensionAttribute1", strMacAddresses
    objComputer.SetInfo
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  I think the preferred option based on everyone's suggestions will be trying to match the objects from the OUs in AD to DHCP.  Any tips on that would be much appreciated.