# How to find the MAC Address of Active Directory Computer Objects?

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory, mac-address

I am trying to get write a script where I can get all of the machine within my domains. here is what I found so far however I need to add additional information and still unable to get the correct information to get pull out. If someone can help me this will be great.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*Windows server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' -Properties  Name,Operatingsystem, OperatingSystemVersion, OperatingSystemServicePack,IPv4Address | Sort-Object -Property Operatingsystem | Select-Object -Property Name,Operatingsystem, OperatingSystemVersion, OperatingSystemServicePack, IPv4Address| ft -Wrap –Auto
```

I still need to be able to grab the MAC Address from all machines as well domains the machine belong to. and to make it worst I need to figure out how to export all of the data to CSV.

Comment: Afaik, yhere is no mac address in AD, meaning that you have to poll each concerned computer in the net network. See also: [How to find mac address in active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266269/how-to-find-mac-address-in-active-directory).

Comment: thank you Santiago I will keep that in mind. this is the first time I am working on scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop over the computers and get the MAC address individually inside the loop:

```
# Get-ADComputer returns these properties by default: 
# DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, GroupScope, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID

$props  = 'OperatingSystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion', 'OperatingSystemServicePack', 'IPv4Address'
$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like '*Windows server*' -and enabled -eq 'true'" -Properties  $props | 
    Sort-Object OperatingSystem | ForEach-Object {
        $mac = if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
            # these alternative methods could return an array of MAC addresses

            # get the MAC address using the IPv4Address of the computer
            (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $_.IPv4Address).MACAddress
            # or use
            # Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.IPv4Address -ScriptBlock { (Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Up'}).MacAddress }
            # or 
            # (& getmac.exe /s $_.IPv4Address /FO csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object { $_.'Transport Name' -notmatch 'disconnected' }).'Physical Address'
        }
        else { $mac = 'Off-Line' }

        # return the properties you want as object
        $_ | Select-Object Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion, OperatingSystemServicePack, IPv4Address,
                           @{Name = 'MacAddress'; Expression = {@($mac)[0]}}
    }

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

# or output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Wherever\ADComputers.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Answer (score 0):

Active directory computer object doesn't contain the MAC address attribute , so you will not be able to get the info needed using active directory object only;  but instead you can use the "IPv4Address" attribute of the AD computer object and query the DHCP server to find the machines MAC address and place the output data as "custompsobject" then export the result as C.V sheet.
Also if you have System center configuration manager "SCCM" you can query its database to generate a report with all needed data (Name,Operatingsystem, OperatingSystemVersion, OperatingSystemServicePack,IPv4Address and MAC address)