# Run powershell command as domain user while deploying Azure Arm Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have an Azure Arm template deployment creating the following resources -

1. 'N' numbers of VMs
2. Joining each VM to an existing AD
3. Running Custom Script Extensions (CSE) on each VM - essentially a PS script to get computer info using "Get-ADComputer" into a CSV from the AD. Simmilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70465812/how-to-find-the-mac-address-of-active-directory-computer-objects)

If I skip step 3 and manually run the script on VM it returns all computers in CSV even if I log in with any user (domain or administrator).
Unfortunately, when I add CSE to the template it isn't working.

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        ...
},
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        ...
        "properties": {
            "type": "JsonADDomainExtension"
            ...
        }
},
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        ...
        "properties": {
            "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
            ...
            "protectedSettings": {
                "commandToExecute": "powershell RunPythonScript.ps1"
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: what s the error messge? also could you share your script `RunPythonScript.ps1`

Comment: you do need to upload your script to the vm as well

Comment: @Thomas I have 3 nested scripts. Getting AD-Computers is the last script. The other 2 scripts are present locally on VM & both are producing results. Only the last one isn't producing result or not getting AD computers. About the error message - Am not getting any. I am getting only host (one I run command from) info in the Get-ADComputer and other nodes isn't returned by Get-ADComputer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to ***upload your powershell-script in Azure storage account > Generate SAS token url and use it to run your PS script as Custom script extension.***

*My Storage account with Powershell script and generated SAS URL:-*

[image]

Powershell Script to run inside Windows Server:-

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Install-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-AD-PowerShell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Get computer information and export it to a CSV file
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Export-Csv -Path "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**My `main.bicep` file:-**

```
// VM with availability set

param resourceLocation string ='North Europe'
@secure()
param adminPassword string = 'silicon@123'

resource appnetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-07-01' = {
  name: 'silic6netk'
  location: resourceLocation
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'SubnetA'
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: '10.0.0.0/24'
        }
      }
      {
        name: 'SubnetB'
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: '10.0.1.0/24'
        }
      }
    ]    }
}

resource app_ip 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2022-07-01' = {
  name: 'sili-ip'
  location: resourceLocation
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
  }
}

resource app_interface 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2022-07-01' = {
  name: 'sili-interface'
  location: resourceLocation
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipConfig1'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          subnet: {            
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'silic6netk', 'SubnetA')
          }
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: app_ip.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: app_nsg.id
    }
  }
}


resource vmstore55434434 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'silicon74'
  location: resourceLocation
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
}

resource app_nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2022-07-01' = {
  name: 'silic-nsg'
  location: resourceLocation
  properties: {
    securityRules: [
      {
        name: 'Allow-RDP'
        properties: {
          description: 'Allow Remote Desktop'
          protocol: 'Tcp'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          destinationPortRange: '3389'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '*'
          access: 'Allow'
          priority: 110
          direction: 'Inbound'
        }
      }
      {
        name: 'Allow-HTTP'
        properties: {
          description: 'Allow HTTP'
          protocol: 'Tcp'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          destinationPortRange: '80'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '*'
          access: 'Allow'
          priority: 120
          direction: 'Inbound'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource appvmconfigapp 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2022-11-01' = {
  parent: appvm
  name: 'appvmconfigapp'
  location: 'North Europe'
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Compute'
    type: 'CustomScriptExtension'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.10'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      fileUris: [
        'https://xxxxnstrg6.blob.core.windows.net/test/GetAd.ps1?sp=xxxxxxxx'
      ]
    }
    protectedSettings: {
      commandToExecute: 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File GetAd.ps1'
    }
  }
}

resource appvm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-11-01' = {
  name: 'silicon74vm'
  location: resourceLocation
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: 'Standard_D2s_v3'
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: 'appvm'
      adminUsername: 'siliconuser'
      adminPassword: adminPassword
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: '2022-Datacenter'
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        name: 'windowsVM1OSDisk'
        caching: 'ReadWrite'
        createOption: 'FromImage'
      }            
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: app_interface.id
        }
      ]
    }
    diagnosticsProfile: {
      bootDiagnostics: {
        enabled: true
        storageUri: reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', toLower('silicon74'))).primaryEndpoints.blob
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

For `Get-ADComputer`  command to work ***you need to install > ActiveDirectory Module, the step to install the Module in Windows client and server*** is given in this [**Blog**](https://4sysops.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/#)